# Why are IonicModule not part of each Lazy Loaded page module

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Every lazy loaded pages are independent modules. A basic Lazy loaded Pages module looks like this.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TestPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(TestPage),
  ],
})
export class TestPageModule {}
```

The `TestPage` is declared. And Import has `IonicPageModule.forChild()` which actually returns an `ngModule` which imports `IonicModule`. From source,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [IonicModule],
  exports: [IonicModule]
})
export class IonicPageModule {

  static forChild(page: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: IonicPageModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: <any>LAZY_LOADED_TOKEN, useValue: page },
        { provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, useValue: page, multi: true },
      ]
    };
  }

}
```

But I do not see IonicModule part of each bundle. Why are ionic components and directives part of IonicModule not part of each lazy loaded module bundles? And can we do that with our own components to avoid code duplication?

Comment: _Why are ionic components and directives part of IonicModule not part of each lazy loaded module bundles_ What do you mean? are you not able to access ionic components in lazy loaded page?

Comment: I am able to. But my question is why is it not part of a Lazy loaded Page module. For example if I import a component module I created in a module it would be part of that bundle. The same way , why are IonicModule not part of each bundle which is imported in all IonicPage modules with ``IonicPageModule.forChild`` function.